# Unnecessary horizontal scrollbar in close as duplicate popup

Tags: bug, design, duplicate-questions, horizontal-scroll-bar

In Firefox (58.0.2 64bit Win7) I see an unnecessary horizontal scrollbar in close as duplicate popup, e.g.:

> [image: scroll]

In Google Chrome such scrollbar appers too, but not for all question. I.e. much rare than in Firefox.

Comment: Just a very curious, unrelated question: did you actually intend to close the question behind the dialog box as a duplicate? I know exactly what that question is, and don't believe it's a dupe.

Comment: @Ano it was just for demonstration the issue, the first question under the mouse pointer :) without willing to close this one.